# TypeError: Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt

Am practicing API testing, and  tryig to run the below test

```
def test_login_user(self):
    with self.app as client:
        with self.app_context():

            client.post('/register',data={'username':'test','password':'1234'})

            auth_response=client.post('/auth',
                                     data=json.dumps({'username':'test','password':'1234'}),
                                     headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

            self.assertIn('access_token',json.loads(auth_response.data).keys())
```

**ended with the fallowing error :**

> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\python39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
> yield   File "c:\python39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 593, in run
> self.*callTestMethod(testMethod)   File "c:\python39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 550, in *callTestMethod
> method()   File "C:\Users\Admin\Flask\app\RestAPI\tests\system\test_user.py", line 28,
> in test_login_user
> auth_response=client.post('/auth',   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py",
> line 1016, in post
> return self.open(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\testing.py",
> line 222, in open
> return Client.open(   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py",
> line 970, in open
> response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)   File
> "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py",
> line 861, in run_wsgi_app
> rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)   File
> "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py",
> line 1096, in run_wsgi_app
> app_rv = app(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 2464, in **call**
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 2450, in wsgi_app
> response = self.handle_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask_restful_*init**.py",
> line 272, in error_router
> return original_handler(e)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1867, in handle_exception
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
> raise value   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 2447, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1952, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask_restful_*init**.py",
> line 272, in error_router
> return original_handler(e)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1821, in handle_user_exception
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
> raise value   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1950, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1936, in dispatch_request
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt_*init*_.py",
> line 125, in _default_auth_request_handler
> access_token = *jwt.jwt_encode_callback(identity)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt_*init**.py",
> line 70, in _default_jwt_encode_handler
> return jwt.encode(payload, secret, algorithm=algorithm, headers=headers)   File
> "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jwt.py", line
> 55, in encode
> return super(PyJWT, self).encode(   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jws.py", line
> 98, in encode
> key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)   File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\MyStoreFW\lib\site-packages\jwt\algorithms.py",
> line 116, in prepare_key
> raise TypeError('Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key.') TypeError: Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key.

I explored all relavant solutions , but failed to fix the issue. please help

Comment: can you print `auth_response.data` and see if there is actually a json formatted token being returned?

Comment: It's    '{NameError}name 'auth_response' is not defined'

Comment: def full_dispatch_request(self):
        "'Dispatches the request and on top of that performs request
        pre and postprocessing as well as HTTP exception catching and
        error handling.

        .. versionadded:: 0.7
        """
        self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
        try:
            request_started.send(self)
            rv = self.preprocess_request()
            if rv is None:
                rv = self.dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
        return self.finalize_request(rv)

Comment: code going into :                             if rv is None: rv = self.dispatch_request() except Exception as e: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) return self.finalize_request(rv)

Comment: where did you put `print(auth_response.data)` ?  you need to put it after you make post request.

Comment: I used auth_response.data after post request @ self.assert, but it is failing  while posting the request itself

Comment: fixed the formatting error. thanks